# function runs on scanner emulator, but not scanner itself (C#, SQL)

Tags: c#, sql, connection-string

I'm developing an add-in for a scanner.  I've run into problems with a specific function that I'm writing.  The problem seems to be with my connection string.  The code runs fine on the scanner emulator, but not on the scanner itself.  Any ideas what could be going on?

I get the error 
An error has occured while establishing a connection to the server.  When connecting to SQL Server 2005, this failure may be caused by the fact... (provider:  Named Pipes Provider, error -  40 Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

The scanner uses Active Directory, I think.  That may be the problem.

The code is as follows:

```
    private bool confirmName(String clientID)
    {

        String clientName = "";

        try
        {
            // Setting up the SqlConnectionStringBuilder
            SqlConnectionStringBuilder buildIt = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
            buildIt.DataSource = "xxx.xx.x.xx";
            buildIt.InitialCatalog = "Test_Clinical";
            buildIt.IntegratedSecurity = true;

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(buildIt.ConnectionString);
            con.Open();
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT First_Name, Last_Name FROM background WHERE Patient_No=@Patient_No", con))
            {
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Patient_No", clientID);
                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    reader.Read();
                    clientName = reader.GetString(0).Trim() + " " + reader.GetString(1).Trim();
                } // end if (reader.hasRows)
                else
                {
                    // No client found for this ID.
                    return false;
                } // end else
            } // end using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT First_Name, Last_Name FROM background WHERE Patient_No=@Patient_No", con))
        } // end try
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
            exporterHost.WriteSystemLog(LogType.Error, "E9999999", "SQL ERROR: " + err.Message);
            return false;
        }

        // At this point, we should have a valid client name.

        // Creating a Dialog and giving it the appropriate text.
        SampleDialog checkIt = new SampleDialog();
        checkIt.setQuestion("Do you want to scan a document for " + clientName + "?");

        if (checkIt.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            return true;
        } // end if (checkIt.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        else
        {
            return false;
        } // end else

    } // end confirmName
```

Comment: Look at the server information that is the reason the actual device cannot connect. The emulator works because its on your local machine and thus the server information is valid.

Comment: I'll look into that.  Thanks!
I'm considering having an account made for the scanner to use, and not using integrated_security = true, but I haven't had much success using that, even with the scanner emulator.

Comment: Even if you do your idea you have to resolve your connection issue.

Comment: Are you talking about the data source?  I just removed the ip address before I posted.
The database I'm connecting to isn't on my local machine.

Answer (score 0):

The system we're using developing for handles SQL connections on a different port for some reason.  That was the problem.

Still curious that it worked on the emulator, but not the hardware though.